# Django ModelForm Inheritance with request.user results in TypeError on __init__

Tags: django, inheritance, modelform

Trying to inherit `ModelForm` to create a `BaseForm` to update `created_by`, `modified_by` fields in model. 
My `BaseForm` is as

```
class BaseForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('request', None).user
        super(BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit']=False
        obj = super(BaseForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.user:
            obj.modified_by = self.user.username            
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Child Form is as

```
class InviteForm(BaseForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserInvitation
```

and I am passing the request in child form through view

```
form = InviteForm(instance=instance,request=request)
```

however it gives error

```
TypeError at /accounts/invitation/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

The error is not there if I do not inherit the `BaseForm` and write the code in child form i.e. `InviteForm`.

Please advise what I am doing wrong, I do not want to repeat the code in each form.

```
Traceback:
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\mysite\userplus\views.py" in invitation
87.         form = InviteForm(instance=instance,request=request)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/invitation/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

Comment: Can you try `def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs): if request: self.user = request.user`?

Comment: Can you post a full traceback?

Comment: Can you try to simply change the kwargs key from `request` to `req`? It might be related to this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20744

Comment: No it does not help, if you see the traceback, error originate from view                                                                   87.         form = InviteForm(instance=instance,request=request)  and it impacts only when ModelForm is inherited

Answer (score -1):

To update the modified_by field that you have in your UserInvitation model, you should exclude it from being shown in the form:

```
class BaseForm(ModelForm):

...

class InviteForm(BaseForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserInvitation
        exclude = ('modified_by',)
```

Then in your view

```
form = InviteForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    invite = form.save(commit=false)
    invite.modified_by = request.user
    invite.save()
```

That way the user making the request is used.

Alternatively, you can set the user beforehand:

```
# views.py
instance = Invite(modified_by=request.user)
form = InviteForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
...
```

Comment: "Try"? This answer showed up in the low quality queue. You should improve it to add more substantial information. It appears like a comment now.

Comment: Hi Tom, this way it works, but the moment I move this code to BaseForm and then inherit the BaseForm, it breaks.

Comment: What error does it give and what exactly did you move?

Comment: I am trying to achieve it DRY way, all my models have these fields (modified_by,created_by) and want to update it in background and not in main form. Hence the inheritance. Want to retain the code modified_by=request.user in BaseForm and not in InviteForm

Comment: When you create your instance that you pass in to the form, you could set the `modified_by` before its passed in ie: `instance = Invite(modified_by=request.user)` 

then do 
`form = InviteForm(request.POST, instance=instance)` 
and that should set it without having to change anything further

Comment: Tom, we can do it, but that is not the intention as it will require to do the same in each form. While I want to set in one time in BaseForm and reuse it by inheriting in every form across my application.

Comment: The above way would only require you to set the user within the view with no changes to the form. If you need to access the user in the form then it would require custom middleware.